# Cloudera CDH4 - how come I can't browse the hdfs filesystem from the nodes?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I installed my test cluster using Cloudera Manager free.
I can only browse the filesystem from the main NameNode.  When running hadoop dfs -ls only shows the local folder.
JPS shows the Jps, TaskTracker, DataNode on the nodes.
MapReduce tasks/jobs run fine on all the nodes as a cluster.

With my custom setup Hadoop cluster (without Cloudera), I can easily browse and manipulate the hdfs filesystem (eg. I can run hadoop dfs -mkdir test1 on all the nodes - but only on the NameNode in CDH4)

why is this?

Comment: local folder means local file system?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command ./bin/hadoop fs -ls / for HDFS browsing.